# Traefik https on additional custom port (8080)

Tags: docker, traefik, lets-encrypt

I use the fictional domain name *backend.mydomain.com* instead of the domain that is acually used for the sake of this question.

I am moving a microservice into a docker environment where traefik proxy is used.
I need the service to be reachable via *https://backend.mydomain.com:8080*.

Other Services run as docker containers that use the default 443 port with their domains, but this specific Service must additionally be reachable on port 8080 via https.

For this purpose, in traefik.yml we have defined

```yaml
entryPoints:
    http:
        address: ":80"
        http:
            redirections:
                entryPoint:
                    to: https
                    scheme: https
    https:
        address: ":443"
        http:
            tls:
                certResolver: http-resolver
    myservice:
         address: ":8080"
         http:
            redirections:
                 entryPoint:
                     to: https
                     scheme: https
```

And on the docker-compose definition for the corresponding Microservice:

```yaml
  myservice:
    #...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.entrypoints=https,myservice"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.rule=Host(`backend.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.myservice.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
```

Within its container the service runs on port 8080 as well, hence the last line in the docker-compose file.
However this approach does not solve my problem:

- It does forward from http://backend.mydomain.com:8080 to https://backend.mydomain.com with a 301 (which is ok, but staying on 8080 would be ok too)
- https://backend.mydomain.com:8080 however gives me a 404

How do I get it to work?
The [traefik documentation on entrypoints](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/redirectscheme/) doesn't really have a lot of info  - Is my approach even the right one?

See also [my related post on the traefic community forum](https://community.traefik.io/t/https-on-additional-custom-port-8080/10587).

Comment: Have you tried: `"traefik.http.routers.myservice.rule=Host(\`backend.mydomain.com\`) || Host(\`backend.mydomain.com:8080\`)"`

Comment: That gives me errors like 

invalid rule Host(`backend.mydomain.com` || Host(`backend.mydomain.com:8080`)), error: *ast.BinaryExpr is not supported

Comment: You've got a typo in that rule, each `Host` has a separate closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thx - fixing that made the errors go away - however the behaviour didn't change, https still gives me a 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://community.traefik.io/t/https-on-additional-custom-port-8080/10587/4?u=iari) and [here](https://community.traefik.io/t/https-on-additional-custom-port-8080/10587/6?u=iari) by traefik discourse-mod cakiwi I have removed the line

```yaml
to: https
```

and added the tls configuration, so the complete entrypoint config in `traefik.yml` now corresponds to

```yaml
    myservice:
         address: ":8080"
         http:
            tls:
                certResolver: http-resolver
            redirections:
                 entryPoint:
                     scheme: https
I noticed that the example configs always specify 'leresolver' however, in our config I find

certificatesResolvers:
    http-resolver:
        acme:
            email: admin@mydomain.com
            storage: /data/acme.json
            httpChallenge:
                entryPoint: http
    tls-resolver:
        acme:
            email: admin@mydomain.com
            storage: /data/acme.json
            tlsChallenge: {}
```

It now works with both ports, 443 and 8080 - without the 301 redirect.